# Proving that the complex numbers: additive/multiplicative identity is unique

Tags: complex-analysis

From an example/solution from my study guide that I was given:

a) Write (x,y) + (u,v) = (x,y) and point out how it follows that the complex number 0 = (0,0) is
unique as an additive identity

b) Likewise, write (x,y) (u,v) = (x,y) and show that the number 1 = (1,0) is a unique multiplicative identity.

Proof
a) Let $(u,v)$ be any complex number such that $(x,y) + (u,v) = (x,y)$ for all $(x,y) ∈ C$.

Then surely:
$(0,0) = (0,0) + (u,v)$  (by assumption)

$= (u,v)$

b)Let $(u,v)$ be given such that $(x,y) (u,v) = (x,y)$ for all $(x,y) ∈ C$.

Then
$(1,0) = (1,0) (u,v)$ (by assumption)

$= (u,v) (1,0)$

$= (u,v)$

My Question

How does this prove that its "$0 = (0,0)$ is unique as an additive identity" we just took one example that happens to be correct. I don't see how this proves uniqueness

Here is my understanding(of what it should be):
a) let $x = (x,y)∈ C$, let $a = (v,u)$ that is the additive identity, thus
$x + a = x$ {1} and $x+b=x$ {2}
Subtract {2} from {1} thus
$x + a-(x+b) = x-x$

thus $a-b = 0$ thus $a=b$

now we know that the additive identity is unique. we can prove that $a=b=0$ by subbing 0 for x into {1} eg:  $0 + a = 0$ thus $a =0$ thus concludes the proof.

(OR)

simply could we just do $x + a = x$, subtract $x$ from each side
thus $a=0$ for all $x∈ C$

b)let $x = (x,y)∈ C$, let $a = (v,u)$ that is the multiplicative identity, thus
$xa = x$ {1} and $xb=x$ {2}.

Subtract {2} from {1} thus
$xa-xb = x-x$

$x(a-b) = 0$
as $x$ is arbitrary, thus $(a-b) = 0$, thus $a=b$

now by subbing 1 for a in $xa = 1$ we get $1a=1$ thus $a =1$ thus concluding the proof.

More Questions
(1) I would like to know whether any of my proofs are valid to proving the uniqueness and

(2) and my first question How does this prove that its "$0 = (0,0)$ is unique as an additive identity"

I would really appreciate any help/ insight you can offer

Comment: I would say that in general in complex arithmetic $(x,y)+(u,v)=(x+u,y+v)$ and $(x,y)(u,v)=(xu-yv,xv+yu)$.  You want these to be equal to $(x,y)$ in each case for all $x$ and $y$, and can solve two simultaneous equations to find unique $u$ and $v$ for that case

Comment: Here is another way it was proven https://stemjock.com/STEM%20Books/Churchill%20Complex%20Variables%208e/Chapter%201/Section%202/Exercise%208/ChurchillCV8es2e8.pdf
I understand this as well apart from the final stage of part b)
I just do get the way in the book so I must be misunderstanding something

Comment: @Henry wow that was a fast reply, I like your way as it keeps the arbitrary vairable  and it feels more complete. but the one in the book seems so simple but I don't feel like it solves it

Answer (score 1):

tl; dr: When we write $(0, 0) = (0, 0) + (u, v) = (u, v)$, we're showing that an *arbitrary* identity element $(u, v)$ for addition is equal to a *particular* identity element $(0, 0)$; and similarly for multiplication.

---

In the hope of illustrating why both proofs are correct, let's reduce matters to the abstract details: Suppose $A$ is a non-empty set equipped with a binary operation $*$, and suppose $e$ and $e'$ are identity elements for $*$, i.e., that
\begin{align*}
&\left.
\begin{aligned}
  e * x = x \\
  x * e = x
\end{aligned}
\right\}\quad\text{for all $x$ in $A$;}
&&\left.
\begin{aligned}
  e' * x = x \\
  x * e' = x
\end{aligned}
\right\}\quad\text{for all $x$ in $A$.}
\end{align*}
Since $x * e' = x$ for all $x$, in particular (taking $x = e$) we have $e * e' = e$. Similarly, since $e * x = x$ for all $x$, in particular (taking $x = e'$) we have $e * e' = e'$. By transitivity of equality, $e = e * e' = e'$.

Comment: @Reuben - the interesting thing about the general proof Andrew D. Hwang gives here is that it requires practically nothing about either the set $A$ or the binary operation $*$. Unlike your proofs, it does not require the existence of inverses. It does not even require that the operation be commutative or associative, which your proofs also use in the background. In fact, it doesn't even require that $A$ have an identity under $*$. It just says that *if* $A$ has an identity, it can have at most one. It applies to many, many situations, not just complex numbers.